# ARC Leads to Large Abandoned Memory

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, instruments, automatic-ref-counting

I converted my entire project to ARC when iOS 5 was released, and haven't had a EXC_BAD_ACCESS yet. However, I've been looking through the Memory Monitor in Instruments lately, and notice that a fair number of objects are being added to the heap whenever I do the same task repeatedly (for instance taking a picture). However, the objects that are added definitely seem like they SHOULDN'T be kept around. Such examples include:

```
- (NSString *)imagesDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *folderDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folderDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    fileManager = nil;
    return folderDirectory;
```

}

where it says the `fileManager` object isn't being released, and this:

```
UIImageView *transitionImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnail];
        transitionImage.center = primeReviewButton.center;
        transitionImage.bounds = primeReviewButton.bounds;
        transitionImage.transform = orientationTransform;
        transitionImage.alpha = 0.0;

        [self.cameraView insertSubview:transitionImage belowSubview:photoNumberBadge];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             transitionImage.alpha = 1; 
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             transitionImage.alpha = 0;
                             transitionImage.image = nil;
                             [transitionImage removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

where it says the `animateWithDuration:` is somehow responsible for the abandoned memory.

I've tried everything I can to get these objects to be released like they should (all Memory Monitor can tell me about them is that they were all Malloc-ed once, and have a retain count of 1). Is this a bug with ARC?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `NSFileManager`, instead of using the `defaultManager`?

Comment: at a guess, when `transitionImage` is being captured by the block(s) it's retain count is being increased. maybe call `[transitionImage release];` after `[UIView....]`?

Comment: @一二三, `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` is not thread safe pre-iOS 5. Mike, I've thought of that, but under ARC I can't send my own release message =/

Comment: Just a thought... are you sure that ARC is actually turned on?